# Update phone contact (Android) via Phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-contacts

Using phonegap, I can get/filter a single contact from contact list. But how to update (add/remove) phone number field. Please help. Thanks alot.

Lets say 1 got a contact name John Smith with 2 phone number [('Home', '1111'), ('Work', '2222')].

- When I try to remove the 'Work' number, just keep the 'Home' one. First get the contact, **try to** remove all number, then add the 'Home' number but I always get both 3 numbers [('Home', '1111'), ('Work', '2222'), ('Home', '1111')]
- Weir that if I try to remove all number, then add nothing, it really remove all the number from contact ?

Here is my code

```
var phoneNumbers = [];
for (...){
        phoneNum = {
            type: ...,
            value: ...,
            pref: false
        };
        phoneNumbers.push(phoneNum);
}

contact = contacts_list[index]; //get the contact need to edit

//try to remove all current phone number
if (contact.phoneNumbers){
            for (var i = 0; i < contact.phoneNumbers.length; i++){
                delete contact.phoneNumbers[i];
                //contact.phoneNumbers[i] = null; //i try this too
                //contact.phoneNumbers[i] = []; //i try this too
            }
        }

//set new phone number
contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
contact.save(...)
```

I also try create a new contact with only 1 number [('Home', '1111')], set id and rawId as same as i contact object I need to update, then save(). But i still get the same result [('Home', '1111'), ('Work', '2222'), ('Home', '1111')]

```
var contact = navigator.contacts.create();
var phoneNumbers = [];
phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('Home', '1111', false);
contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
contact.id = ...
contact.rawId = ...
contact.save(...);
```

this also

```
contact = contacts_list[index]; //get the contact need to edit

//try to remove all current phone number
if (contact.phoneNumbers){
            for (var i = 0; i < contact.phoneNumbers.length; i++){
                delete contact.phoneNumbers[i];
                //contact.phoneNumbers[i] = null; //i try this too
                //contact.phoneNumbers[i] = []; //i try this too
            }
        }
var phoneNumbers = [];
phoneNumbers[0] = new ContactField('Home', '1111', false);
contact.phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers;
contact.save(...)
```

Comment: you got your answer or still waiting for it???

Answer (score 2):

In the contact plugin of cordova, you can save the contact passing the original contact id, it will update the contact details in the database.

Here is an example:

```
//Set the options for finding conact
var options = new ContactFindOptions();
options.filter   = 'Bob'; //name that you want to search
options.multiple = false;

var fields = ["id","displayName", "phoneNumbers"];

navigator.contacts.find(fields, sucessUpdate, onError, options);

function sucessUpdate(contacts) {
    var contact = contacts[0]; //found contact array must be one as we disabled multiple false

    // Change the contact details
    contact.phoneNumbers[0].value = "999999999";
    contact.name = 'Bob';
    contact.displayName = 'Mr. Bob';
    contact.nickname = 'Boby'; // specify both to support all devices
    // Call the "save" function on the object
    contact.save(function(saveSuccess) {
        alert("Contact successful update");
    }, function(saveError){
        alert("Error when updating");
    });
}
function onError(contactError) 
{
  alert("Error = " + contactError.code);
}
```

Comment: How do I save updated phone number. It creates duplicate on save

Comment: when you call `contact.save` it automaticaly save the contact